# How to convert Scripting.Dictionary to a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, plugins, com, activex

Is there any way to convert an ActiveX (Scripting.Dictionary) to a JavaScript object?

I need to expose some constants, defined in an ActiveX, to JavaScript code. Right now I'm returning a Scripting.Dictionary, so JavaScript can access them like this:

myObj.SomeEnum("SOME_CONST");

where SomeEnum is defined in the IDL as a property, returning VARIANT (which at runtime wraps IDispatch pointer to a dictionary object).

However, ideally I'd want to be able to access the same thing like this:

myObj.SomeEnum.SOME_CONST.

Is there any way to do this? I don't want to define specific COM interface for each such enum/property.

Comment: The SomeEnum property is of type Scripting.Dictionary?

Comment: Well, I can make it any type I like, the code above (SomeEnum("SOME_CONST")) works if I return the interface pointer, wrapped into VARIANT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var javascript_array = new VBArray(dictionary.Items()).toArray();
```

Comment: Hmm, JavaScript gives error: VBArray expected. I know it works for SAFERRAY, but what should I pass in case of a dictionary? IDispatch pointer, as well as VARIANT (wrapping IDispatch pointer) don't work.

Comment: But that strips keys from my dictionary: items now get indexed by ordinals, not by their original keys. But I guess I can call the same code with Keys() as well as Items(), and then combine what I get in JavaScript. Thanks!